# 2 Ad Hoc Distribution profiles with same name listed when I build my ipa

Tags: xcode, xcode5, provisioning

This stuff still confuses me. I added a device to my Ad Hoc profile in the developer portal, downloaded and double clicked the downloaded file. Nothing appeared to hapopen so I went into the Organizer in  xCode 5, selected Editor->Provisioning Profiles->Import Profile.

Now when I build my ipa for distribution the profile is listed twice. I picked the first one in the list and discovered that it did not have the new device, so I redid the build, picked the second one and it worked as expected.

I do not understand exactly why I have gotten myself into this situation nor how to remove the old profile.

Here is what my code signing in xcode looks like. Should I delete and start over. If so which ones do I delete?

[image]

Thanks,

John

Comment: you fix your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this in XCode 5 is using an [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). It lets you manually delete duplicates of provisioning profiles with ease and speed.

[image]

I keep Xcode closed when I do this just in case.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I did not know that this utility existed. I downloaded it then used it to easily identify which profile to delete and deleted it.

Comment: I had to use this just now when XCode ended-up with two local variants of an AdHoc profile - which was making exporting of the .ipa file needlessly complicated. Many thanks!